# Between Group comparison for parameters measured on different time points

Tags: anova, mixed-model, panel-data, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset of 100 patients for whom data was recorded of 3 different parameters say Heart rate, temperature and ETCO2 levels which are measured in 3 phases eg. Phase 0, Phase 1 and Phase 2. The 3 parameters in each phase has multiple measurements taken as unequal time points in between phases.

eg. In phase 1,parameters have been measured at 0hr, 12hr, 24hr, 72hr,
In phase 2 - 10mins, 20mins, 30 mins, 
In phase 3-  30 mins, 60 mins , 90 mins

In ideal situations, I would have used mixed methods ANOVA or LMM.
But I am stuck with this.

Can anyone suggest what model would be best to do a between group and within subject analysis?

Comment: It is not clear how exactly you want to analyze the data, i.e., do you want to analyze the parameters separately? Do you want to analyze the different phases separately?

Comment: Yes, the parameters will be analysed separately. But for each parameter (measured repeatedly) we will be looking for change in each phase.